# Android NDK| native library for USB storage management.

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, c-libraries

I am trying to build an app which involves formatting usb drives, changing the partition scheme and creating partitions. 
After a lot of research I found that Android SDK does not provide tools or ways to access the information needed to do such tasks even with root.

So is there any C/C++ library which I could use? Or is there a better way?